# How can I search for an exact value in a cell of the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, equals

I have a `DataGridView` instance named `dataGridView` with some rows in it. Now I want to search in the `dataGridView` for an exact value of cell and use that specific row to get cell data from another cell, and use it's value.

In my dataGridView I have 4 rows: `Name`, `Filename`, `Path`, `HotKey`.

When I press a key combination it has to match exactly with the registered `HotKey` combination in my cell.

For example:
`HotKey == F1`, this means when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> it will use the `Path` cell for a string I need in the project.

Problem: 
When I press <kbd>F1</kbd> that works great. 
But when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then it uses also the same data from F1 that same row It should do nothing when there is no cells with the Value `CTRL+F1`, `ALT+F1` or `Shift+F1`.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I use:

```
public string typedChars = string.Empty;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string CTRL = (e.Control ? "CTRL + " : "");
    string ALT = (e.Alt ? "ALT + " : "");
    string SHIFT = (e.Shift ? "Shift + " : "");
    string KEYPRESSED = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    typedChars = $"{CTRL}{ALT}{SHIFT}{KEYPRESSED}"; // Puts all pressed key combination to a string for the HotKey combination

    for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count); i++) //counting all the rows
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(typedChars)) // search for an exact value in cell 3 and find that row (HotKey)
        {
            String Path = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(); //use from that founded row the cell 2 value (Path)
            //do something here with the value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, 
this script is good. It was called also somewhere else from the script at the same time. So I had a dubble HotKey call to that sellect row. One was <kbd>F1</kbd> and one was <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> that made look like <kbd>F1</kbd> was also doing something.